# Использование async/await в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, асинхронность

Почитал про использование `async`/`await` в других языках программирования и не совсем понял, как и когда их используют. Для чего они вообще нужны? С помощью них можно улучшить уже существующий код? В каких случаях не стоит их использовать?

> PEP 492 introduced support for native coroutines and async / await syntax to Python 3.5. A notable limitation of the Python 3.5 implementation is that it was not possible to use await and yield in the same function body. In Python 3.6 this restriction has been lifted, making it possible to define asynchronous generators:

```
async def ticker(delay, to):
    """Yield numbers from 0 to *to* every *delay* seconds."""
    for i in range(to):
        yield i
        await asyncio.sleep(delay)
```

> PEP 530 adds support for using async for in list, set, dict comprehensions and generator expressions:

```
result = [i async for i in aiter() if i % 2]
```

> Additionally, await expressions are supported in all kinds of comprehensions:

```
result = [await fun() for fun in funcs if await condition()]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Смотрите. Async/await нужен для того, чтобы не блокировать поток выполнения на время ожидания какого-нибудь асинхронного события. Конструкция Async/await превращает по сути процедуру в *корутину* (сопрограмму): она прекращает своё выполнение на время `await`, дожидается асинхронного события, и возобновляет работу.

В не-async-варианте ожидание получается блокирующим, или нужно вручную делать трюки: запускать операцию и подписываться на её окончание. Async делает код более простым, линейным.

Пример (на псевдокоде):

Async:

```
DownloadToFile(url):
    filename = GetFilename()
    content = await DownloadUrl(url)
    WriteToFile(filename, content)
    ReportSuccess()
```

Не-async:

```
DownloadToFile(url):
    filename = GetFilename()
    BeginDownloadUrl(url, onfinished: lambda content: StoreContent(content, filename))

StoreContent(content, filename)
    WriteToFile(filename, content)
    ReportSuccess()
```

Вы видите, что без async контекст выполнения (локальные переменные и т. п.) приходится передавать в «хвост» функции (continuation) вручную. Если async-вызовов много, аналогичный код без async быстро становится сложным.

---

Важное отличие async- от синхронной функции — async-функция возвращается к вызывающему коду в момент первого выполнения await (если тот ещё не завершён). Вызывающий код может дождаться полного окончания работы при помощи await, а может и продолжить работу самостоятельно.

---

Использование async/await имеет смысл там, где у вас есть ожидание, не связанное с нагрузкой на процессор. Например, ожидание прихода данных из интернета, или чтения файла с диска. В этом случае вы освобождаете физический поток выполнения для системы, но логическое выполнение продолжается (после возврата из `await`).

Comment: по моему Вы в этом ответе упустили важный момент. Если `DownloadUrl` еще не завершена, то управление сразу возвращается из `DownloadToFile` в ее caller, который будет работать параллельно с DownloadUrl и он (caller) в свое время должен вызывать await. (я запомнил это из Вашего аналогичного объяснения для шарпа (но откровенно говоря, мне не кажется, что await упрощает параллельное программирование, делая в общем случае логику программы более понятной и свободной от ошибок))

Comment: @avp: Я не знаю, как это реализовано в Питоне, поэтому боюсь говорить что-то определённое. Но да, это важное дополнение.